# Cordova app throws a CORS error when connecting to a production API

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cordova, cors

I have my app on local environment and trying to test my newly deployed backend api (Laravel) on Hostinger, when trying to connect with it, it throws me a CORS error.
Here is the sample log at my network tab : [image]

Q : If I build the APK, is this will occur? How can I fix this in a first place?

Here is the .env file of my app

```
VUE_APP_NAME="SSIS"
VUE_APP_API_URL=https://psussis-online.preview-domain.com
VUE_APP_APP_VERSION=2.0.0
VUE_APP_API_KEY="HWmxFAQajmY="
```

Here is the .htacess file of my deployed Backend

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all create a middleware name cors and register it on kernel.php.
After that on the route group add this middleware on the routes/api.php.

The middleware code is-

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    // ALLOW OPTIONS METHOD
    $headers = [
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods'=> 'POST, GET, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Headers'=> 'Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With'
    ];
    if($request->getMethod() == "OPTIONS") {
        // The client-side application can set only headers allowed in Access-Control-Allow-Headers
        return Response::make('OK', 200, $headers);
    }

    $response = $next($request);
    foreach($headers as $key => $value)
        $response->header($key, $value);
    return $response;
}
```

Now on the routes/api.php

```
 Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function (){//your routes});
```

Comment: Unless it's a public API, `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` shouldn't be `*`.